# Setting the nib file results to the simulator work, but the iPhone device not load

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I set the Target > info > property > main nib file  as MainWindow, in the simulator, it works, but in the device, the screen black, and no "viewDidLoad" is called. What's wrong with that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth checking: did you get the case of the NIB file name correct?

OS X is *not* case sensitive, so it would consider `MainView.xib` to be the same as `mAiNvIeW.xib` but the iPhone *is* case sensitive, so they'd be considered different files.